# Magento 2.3.5-p2 on PHP 7.3: PHP Parse error syntax error, unexpected 'Escaper' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Tags: magento2.3, php

Get the following error message.

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Escaper' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /app/code/Cyberic/Performance/Controller/Retrieve/Dependency.php on line 54
```

This is the code in the above file

```
<?php

namespace Cyberic\Performance\Controller\Retrieve;

use Cyberic\Performance\Model\JsBundleFactory;
use Cyberic\Performance\Model\ResourceModel\JsBundle as JsBundleResourceModel;
use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw as RawResult;
use Magento\Framework\Escaper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\InvalidRequestException;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw;
use Magento\Framework\App\CsrfAwareActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Url;

class Dependency extends Action implements CsrfAwareActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var SerializerInterface
     */
    private $jsonSerializer;

    /** @var  JsonFactory */
    private $jsonFactory;

    /**
     * @var JsBundleFactory
     */
    private $jsBundleFactory;

    /**
     * @var JsBundleResourceModel
     */
    private $jsBundleResourceModel;

    /** @var  Http */
    protected $_request;

    /**
     * @var RawFactory
     */
    protected $resultRawFactory;

    /**
     * @var Escaper
     */
    private Escaper $escaper;

    /**
     * @var Url
     */
    private Url $url;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param RawFactory $resultRawFactory
     * @param Escaper $escaper
     * @param SerializerInterface $jsonSerializer
     * @param JsonFactory $jsonFactory
     * @param JsBundleFactory $jsBundleFactory
     * @param JsBundleResourceModel $jsBundleResourceModel
     * @param Url $url
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
        Escaper $escaper,
        SerializerInterface $jsonSerializer,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory,
        JsBundleFactory $jsBundleFactory,
        JsBundleResourceModel $jsBundleResourceModel,
        Url $url
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->jsonSerializer = $jsonSerializer;
        $this->jsonFactory = $jsonFactory;
        $this->jsBundleFactory = $jsBundleFactory;
        $this->jsBundleResourceModel = $jsBundleResourceModel;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    /**
     * Receive the RequireJs dependency to save in the DB.
     *
     * @return Json
     * @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection
     * @noinspection PhpUnusedLocalVariableInspection
     */
    public function execute(): Json
    {
        $data = $this->jsonSerializer->unserialize($this->_request->getContent());
        if (isset($data['deps'])) {
            foreach ($data['deps'] as $dependencyPath) {
                /**
                 * Prevent javascript modules already bundled or with full URL paths
                 */
                if (strpos($dependencyPath, 'js/bundle/') !== false || filter_var($data['deps'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $dependencyPath = $this->setDependencyPath($dependencyPath);
                $dependencyName = $this->setDependencyName($dependencyPath, $data['paths']);
                if (empty($dependencyName)) {
                    continue;
                }
                $jsBundle = $this->jsBundleFactory->create();
                $jsBundle->setData('page_type', $data['route']);
                $jsBundle->setData('dependency_name', $dependencyName);
                $jsBundle->setData('dependency_path', $dependencyPath);
                try {
                    $this->jsBundleResourceModel->save($jsBundle);
                } catch (Exception $exception) {
                    // insert ignore
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->jsonFactory->create()->setData([
            'result' => true
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @param $dependencyPath
     * @return string
     */
    protected function setDependencyPath($dependencyPath): string
    {
        $search = ['.min.js','jquery/jquery.storageapi','ui/template'];
        $replace = ['.js','jquery/jquery.storageapi.min','Magento_Ui/templates'];

        return str_replace($search, $replace, $dependencyPath);
    }

    /**
     * @param $dependencyPath
     * @param $paths
     * @return string
     */
    protected function setDependencyName($dependencyPath, $paths): string
    {
        if (substr($dependencyPath, -5) == '.html') {
            return 'text!' . $dependencyPath;
        }
        if (substr($dependencyPath, -3) == '.js') {
            $modulePath = substr($dependencyPath, 0, -3);
            foreach ($paths as $alias => $moduleName) {
                if ($modulePath == $moduleName) {
                    return str_replace(['text'], ['mage/requirejs/text'], $alias);
                }
            }
            return str_replace(['jquery/ui-modules'], ['jquery-ui-modules'], $modulePath);
        }

        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Create exception in case CSRF validation failed.
      *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return InvalidRequestException|null
     * @noinspection PhpUndefinedMethodInspection
     */
    public function createCsrfValidationException(RequestInterface $request): ?InvalidRequestException
    {
        /** @var RawResult $response */
        $response = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
        $response->setHttpResponseCode(400);
        $response->setContents('');

        return new InvalidRequestException($response);
    }

    /**
     * Prevent the Ajax controller from being accessed directly from the browser and force same website origin
     *
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @return bool|null
     */
    public function validateForCsrf(RequestInterface $request): ?bool
    {
        /** @var $request Http */
        return $request->isPost() && $request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $this->url->isOwnOriginUrl();
    }
}
```

Running Magento 2.3.5-p2 with PHP 7.3

I'm unsure as to what and how to fix the above error.

Line 54 is

```
private Escaper $escaper;
```

and

```
private Url $url;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **You can remove the class name and try like this:**

```
/**
 * @var Escaper
 */
private $escaper;

/**
 * @var Url
 */
private $url;
```

**After changes please run the upgrade and cache clean command.**

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
private Escaper $escaper;
```

to

```
private $escaper;
```

And

```
private Url $url;
```

to

```
private $url;
```

seems to have fixed the issue.